Summation of arithmetic series
How to represent a sum of $n$ items of an arithmetic series with the use of the sigma notation?
For the sum of the 10 first items, is the below one correct?
$$
\color{gray}{
\sum_{\{{x_i: x_{i-1}+k \}}}^{i = 10} x_i
}
$$
Or maybe:
$$
\sum_{\{{x_i: x_0+i\Delta\}}}^{i=10} x_i
$$
where $\Delta$ is the difference between adjacent items.
It is important (for me) that the series definition/description is below and/or above $\Sigma$, not as an extra expression somewhere before/after the sigma summation.

Interesting Issue, (1) Why do you want it that way ? (2) Your notation is not right because it is not indicating Initial value for $i$ (3) It is more-over not indicating Initial value $x_0$ (4) We can change it easily to include $ki+c$ itself.

(1) What is other way? Eventually, arithmetic series can be defined outside but how to define such? (2/3) I added another example, maybe now it's correct?

In book  David Gries, Fred B. Schneider , A Logical Approach to Discrete Math ,Springer, 1993, page 142 for sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} x_k = x_1+ x_2+ \cdots + x_n$ you can find alternative linear notation  $(+k:\mathbb{N}|1\leqslant k \leqslant n : x_k)$ - may be this helps to write exlplicitly what you want.

While you say it's important to you that the series definition be in the summation's superscript or subscript, my advice is not to do that. $x_i$ can be defined somewhere (in a sentence!) as $x_0+i\Delta$, and the sum can go from $i=1$ to $10$. Inventing new notation when there's already well-established notation is just going to make your readers' lives harder.

ok, it sounds as best solution to that

Linear notation for sum, which I show in my previous comment, has the reserve of writing the definition for $x_k$ at the end, so it will be directly inside sum definition, not somewhere "below and/or above Σ" as is required in OP.

Why is the first sum gray? It makes it hard to read.

Both are incorrect, because the way you specify the range for the iterator i is wrong. It would be understood as i would only take the value of $10$ and not over the range of $0$ to $10$ (assuming that it starts from $0$)
You'd have to include the entire range of values for $i$
$$\sum_{\begin{matrix}0 \leq i \leq n\\ a_i = a_0 + i\Delta \end{matrix}}a_i$$
A more convenient way though is to define the corresponding arithmetic sequence. Let $(a_i)_{i = 0}^\infty, a_i = a_0 + i\Delta$ be our arithmetic sequence, then the sum is simply
$$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} a_i$$

If this is accepted answer, then why not use simply $$\sum_\limits{\begin{matrix}0 \leqslant i \leqslant n \end{matrix}}(a_0 + i\Delta)$$ ?

In section 2.1 Notation of chapter 2 Sums of Concrete Mathematics by R. L. Graham, D. E. Knuth and O. Patashnik we find at formula (2.4):

Formally, we write
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{P(k)}a_k\tag{2.4}
 \end{align*}
as an abbreviation for the sum of all terms $a_k$ such that $k$ is an integer satisfying a given property $P(k)$. (A ''property $P(k)$" is any statement about $k$ that can be either true or false.)

Following this convention we can write the sum of an arithmetic sequence with initial value $a$ and common difference $d$ as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(a+(k-1)d\right)=\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}\left(a+(k-1)d\right)
=\color{blue}{\sum_{{a_k=a+(k-1)d}\atop{1\leq k\leq n}}a_k}
\end{align*}
where the rightmost sum is written at the cost of explicitly introducing a variable $a_k$, which is then used as summand.

Considering that a sum of the roots of a cubic function can be written as (example based on the integral of $ax^3+bx^2+c$ on WolframAlpha):
$$
\sum_{\{{\omega: a\omega^3+b\omega^2+c\omega = 0\}}} \omega
$$
It seems that a possible solution could be:
$$
\sum_{\substack{\{{x_i: x_i = x_0+(i-1)\Delta\}} \\ i=\{{1 \dots n\}}}} x_i
$$
with $\Delta$ being the difference between two adjacent terms.
Still, best option is to define a set beyond $\Sigma$:
$$
\mathfrak{s} = \{{
x_n \ |\  x_n = x_0 + \Delta (n-1)
\ \land\ 
n \in \langle 1,10 \rangle
\}}
$$
And reference it later on:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{10} \mathfrak{s}_n
$$

Of course, this is not usual/known, but In linear notation of sum it will be $(+k:\mathbb{N}|1\leqslant k \leqslant 10 : x_k=x_0 + \Delta (k-1))$.
